# Knockout.js: Select dropdown issue, always sets the "selected item" to the first option even when provided using "initial data"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wenbert/W2qLz/2/

Even though I have provided the "initial data" for the `selected_skill` array, the `$data` becomes the first item in the select box.

```
var initialData = [
    {
    id: '1',
    name: "Batman",
    isDelete: false,
    selected_skill: {              <--- This part right here.
        id: '2',
        name: "Boxing",
        isDeleted: false
    },
    skills: [
        {
        id: '1',
        name: "Karate",
        isDeleted: false},
    {
        id: '2',
        name: "Boxing",
        isDeleted: false
    },
    {
        id: '6',
        name: "Sonar",
        isDeleted: false}
    ]},
{
    id: '2',
    name: "Hulk",
    isDelete: false,
    skills: [
        {
        id: '3',
        name: "MMA",
        isDeleted: false},
    {
        id: '4',
        name: "Rage",
        isDeleted: false},
    {
        id: '5',
        name: "Extra Strength",
        isDeleted: false}
    ]},
    ];
```

See the `$data` part in the screenshot below

[image]

I have the `initial_data` provided but when everything is "loaded", $data is automatically updated based on the first option for the select box.

How do I set the "selected option" this way?

In the screenshot, the `selected_skill` should have been:

```
selected_skill: {
    id: '2',
    name: "Boxing",
    isDeleted: false
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wenbert/W2qLz/2/

**UPDATE:**

The `initialData` in my real app is loaded using `$.getJSON()`. I do it with something like this:

```
$.getJSON(appUrl+"/getstuff/hero.json", 
    function(data){
        ko.applyBindings(new Hero(data));
    }
);
```

I can see that the result from the Firebug Console says that it is "Boxing" - I get `Object { id="2", nameL: "Boxing", isDelete: false }`. But then when everything has been rendered, the `selected_skill` is becomes the first option.

I hope this is making sense. If not, I would be glad to answer clarifications through the comments.

**FINAL UPDATE**

I used:

```
return item.id() === data.selected_skill.id
```

instead of

```
return data.selected_skill && skill.id === data.selected_skill.id;
```

then it worked.

I have marked the correct answer.

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML in firebug/chrome dev console, it seems like the value of the option element doesn't get assigned at all. So there's no value for the selected_skill to match. Maybe you can start from there.

Comment: I'm not sure what mean. But even when you click on the 'gray box' and then click "Set as default" and look at the inspector in the dev console, you won't be able to see the html changed - but the value of the select box is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `selected_skill` object is a different object that the one in skills array rather than a reference to the same object.

In JavaScript,

```
var a = { name: "Bob" };
var b = { name: "Bob" };
var c = a;

alert(a === b);  //false - different objects
alert(a === c);  //true - reference to the same object
```

You would need to run some logic to match the selected object with one from the list.  Maybe something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/W2qLz/3/

Comment: RP Niemeyer, thanks so much for the JS object explaination. That is definitely what I want. BUT on my app, I am fetching the initial data via `$.getJSON()` - I have new logic to match the selected object from the list but I still get the first option. FYI, the JSON result has "Boxing" but when the data is rendered, it is "defaulted" to the first option. Your thoughts?

Comment: rp-niemeyer, I have updated my question with the `$.getJSON()`

Comment: I used: `return item.id() === data.selected_skill.id` instead of `return data.selected_skill && skill.id === data.selected_skill.id;` then it worked.